# Listing employees whose employee number is divisible by some given number

Tags: java

Here I want to improve the code in `addListofEmployees` and `mainMethod`. How can I do so?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class AddEmployees extends Employee {

    public static List<Employee> addListOfEmployees(long upperLimit) {

        List<Employee> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (long i = 0; i < upperLimit; i++) {
            list.add(new Employee(i));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static List<Employee> getAllNumbersDividedByProvidedNumber(long upperLimit, int divideBy) {
        return AddEmployees.addListOfEmployees(upperLimit).parallelStream()
                .filter(Employee -> Employee.getNumber() % divideBy == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    public static void mainMethod() {
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter upper limit as lower is zero");
            long upperLimit = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the number you want to divide with");
            int divideBy = sc.nextInt();

            for (Employee e : AddEmployees.getAllNumbersDividedByProvidedNumber(upperLimit, divideBy)) {
                System.out.println(e.getNumber());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally {
            if (sc != null)
                sc.close();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainMethod();
    }
}

Employee Class

package com.lambada.filter_predicatemethod;

public class Employee {

    private long number;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

}
```

**Edit**

I thinks this can achieving same result but not sure that chaining is a good part

```
public static List<Employee> getEmployeeDividedBy(long upperLimit, long dividedby) {
        return LongStream.range(0, upperLimit).mapToObj(Employee::new).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                .filter(Employee -> Employee.getNumber() % dividedby == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

**AddEmployee.java**:

```
private AddEmployees() {}

public static List<Employee> createListOfEmployees(long upperLimit) {
    return LongStream.range(0, upperLimit)
                     .mapToObj(Employee::new)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static List<Employee> getAllNumbersDividedByProvidedNumber(long upperLimit, int divideBy) {
    return createListOfEmployees(upperLimit).parallelStream()
            .filter(Employee -> Employee.getNumber() % divideBy == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Note that the constructor is declared **`private`** since it is useless in this context. Also, **`addListOfEmployees`** is not the best possible name; I used **`createListOfEmployees`** instead.

Also, since you are printing employees, it would be very nice if they have overriden the **`toString`** method.

All in all, I had this in mind:

**Employee.java**:

```
public class Employee {

    private final long number;

    public Employee() {
        this(0L);
    }

    public Employee(long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[Employee ID: " + number + "]";
    }
}
```

**AddEmployees.java**:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

public class AddEmployees extends Employee {

    private AddEmployees() {}

    public static List<Employee> createListOfEmployees(long upperLimit) {
        return LongStream.range(0, upperLimit)
                         .mapToObj(Employee::new)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static List<Employee> getAllNumbersDividedByProvidedNumber(long upperLimit, int divideBy) {
        return createListOfEmployees(upperLimit).parallelStream()
                .filter(Employee -> Employee.getNumber() % divideBy == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of employees: ");
        int numberOfEmployees = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the divisor: ");
        int divisor = sc.nextInt();

        getAllNumbersDividedByProvidedNumber(numberOfEmployees, 
                                             divisor)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Additional advice**

You can shorten your **`getEmployeeDividedBy`** a bit:

```
public static List<Employee> getEmployeeDividedBy(long upperLimit, long dividedby) {
    return LongStream.range(0, upperLimit)
                     .filter(l -> l % dividedby == 0)
                     .mapToObj(Employee::new)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note that I removed **`.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()`** since it is not required. Also, I first filter, and map only after that since this prunes away some pointless computation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: isn't that mandatory to create a parameterized constructor for  ` this(0L);` ?
just asking....

Comment: The fields declared **`final`** require explicit assignment in the constructor. Since the usage of **`final`** is mostly the matter of taste, feel free to ignore it altogether.

Comment: i ll keep that in mind ... and thanks for the review :)

Comment: You are most welcome. :^)

Comment: I just added a method , is that good to chain methods like I did

Comment: @AsteriskNinja Yes, it is, yet  you can write it shorter; see my update in my answer.

Comment: Well, I ain't Stream API expert myself, and allow NetBeans to guide me through that stream mess.

Answer (score 2):

#### `try-with-resources`

You should use [`try-with-resource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for safe and efficient handling of the underlying `Scanner` I/O resource:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // no need for the redundant mainMethod() method
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        // ...
    } // no need for manual handling of catch/finally here
}
```

#### Parallel streams - required?

What's the purpose of doing a parallelized stream?

#### Simpler approach

Will you be able to consider using a `for`-loop with an increment of `divideBy`?

```
public static List<Employee> getNumbersDivisibleBy(long upperLimit, int divideBy) {
    List<Employee> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (long i = 0; i < upperLimit; i += divideBy) {
        results.add(new Employee(i));
    }
    return results;
}
```

This eliminates creating redundant `Employee` instances in the first place.